# Deploying third party dll in MVC application on appharbor

Tags: appharbor

We are using one third party dll(GflAx.dll) in our project(MVC 4 application) which we register to the local PC using regsvr command. How to register that dll from apphorbor while deploying project via basic git to appharbor.

Comment: I got below answer from appharbor support :-

You can't install dlls on the platform, but perhaps this can solved by bin-deploying the binary.

Comment: please refer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636406/appharbor-thirdy-party-dll-and-gac-referenced-dll