# appharbor: thirdy party .dll and GAC referenced .dll

Tags: cloud, appharbor

1.We are using Appharbor for my client app having number of third party .dll files(for SMS and Email) and 
some of them we referencing form GAC.

some of them we put into /bin folder and referencing form that folder (we set Local Copy = True for .dll file)

I want best way to handle GAC and other third party .dll maintain in appharbor. 
If i need to put that .dll in /bin or any other folder which is in project.

1. Give me the way to handle Physical file in apphabor / or using CDN.
2. Give me the way to use dedicated sql server in appharbor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead [bin deployment](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx), i go through another way.

I created /lib folder at the root of solution and saved all Third-party .dll and GAC .dll 
then I referenced that dlls to my projects, finally it works fine. 
I got one error about adding reference in my project as

"A reference to the "....dll" could not be added.Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

using below like i converted into appropriate .net assembly.

[A reference to the dll could not be added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456758/a-reference-to-the-dll-could-not-be-added)

Then I able to add my dll into project. After adding dll it Local Copy property is disabled so that why i not prefered to used bin-deploy.

1. If all dll you added using nuget then its fine, you will not get any issue.
2. If some dll are not available on nuget the 
   Put that dlls in /lib folder created at root level of solution. 
   or use bin deploy.

Moral: All dependency related to Third-party .dll and GAC dll put into your project and refer it form project.

Refernces:
http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/72603-third-party-dll-and-gac-referenced-dll-not-woking-in-appharbor